# Where should I put FCM configuration in flutter app exactly?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using `firebase_messaging` plugin in my flutter app to handle app notifications (given from a Laravel server). So far, I've successfuly installed the plugin in my project. Tested it on a page, it works.

But in the doc's [example page](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart), it's only demonstrate the usage of a single page. In reality, most of the apps has or may have many pages and each page has it's own notification channels, so does my app.

So.. Where is the exact location to put it's configuration? Should I configure it one each page, or can I just put it on `main.dart` and subscribe every channel from that page?

I don't think the first option is a best practice. Since I'm trying to follow DRY principle and avoid code-duplication to make it easier to maintain the app in the future. Any clue?

Comment: In my experience, put it as early as possible in the app widget tree, and only call it once. Personally, I call it from initState in my home page, not in main. It works for me.

Comment: so put all the logic in a home page right?

Comment: I have a subfolder the contains my helper dart files. The fcm config stuff (onMessage etc.) is held in a file called  fcmHandler.dart that is called at the start of initState in my home page.